# Maven dependency does not update

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem with Maven.

I used to use the `6.0.5 mysql-connector` but because of some serverTime error I wanted to go back to an older version, but after that I receive:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Everything stays the same only the dependency has changed:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

changes to:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven appears to update the jars properly, only somehow the compiler doesn't see them. Any idea what may cause the problem? When I go back to 6.0.5 version no error appears.

Comment: You may want to add whether you run this from the command line or your IDE (which one?), and after which action the error occurs.

Comment: Try a maven update (or mvn clean install -U)

Comment: you are downgrading the version of the dependency controversial to the title.

Comment: I tried  mvn install  before, won't helped. Same as mvn clean instal and  mvn clean install -U. The IDE is IntelliJ, I'm started to think i screwed up something in the settings when I tried make hidden the "out" and "target" folder.

Answer (score 1):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html :

> The name of the class that implements java.sql.Driver in MySQL Connector/J has changed from com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. The old class name has been deprecated.

So I presume you updated the Driver classname to the `cj` package when you upgraded to 6.0.5, but you should change it back to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` make things work with 5.1.38.

Comment: Meh, that was just mistake of mine putting that error. I tried different location of Driver.